# Math notation for testing whether a number is less than two numbers

Tags: inequality, notation

Given numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ what's the correct math notation for testing whether $a$ is less than or equal to $b$ and $c$.

1) $$a \leq b \land a \leq c$$

2) $$a \leq b \land c$$

3) $$a \leq \{b, c\}$$

4) $$a \leq (b, c)$$

Comment: Is this an actual test question (or homework, or something else similar) that you've been asked? Or are you just curious how one would write such a thing, and these are the options you've considered so far?

Comment: These are the options I've considered, I'm from a programming background and this is part of my algorithm I'm trying to turn into math notation.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it just as $a\leq b, c$. It's common enough when you, for instance, want to multiply all different pairs of elements from some indexed collection $\{a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ to use $a_i\cdot a_j$ for $0\leq i, j\leq n$, meaning exactly that $0\leq i\leq n$ and $0\leq j\leq n$.

If you want to get technically strict, then any of the following will do:
$$a\leq b \land a\leq c\\
a\leq b \text{ and }a\leq c\\
a\leq \min(b, c)$$
Of these I prefer the middle one, because to me it is the easiest one to read and immediately understand.

Answer (score 1):

1) is correct if $\wedge$ means "and".  Of course it is better to just write "and".

2) is correct if $\wedge$ means "minimum".  But of course do not just write it without explanation.

Probably 3) could be correct, with the right interpretations.

I think 4) is wrong in any interpretation I can think of.

Since you say this is part of an algorithm, the answer will be determined by what $\wedge$ was defined to be in that course or book.